# Dynamically switching connect in Modelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

Assume I have a large connector involving all kinds of base types (Real, Integer, String, Boolean). How can I switch connections based on state events?
I would like to do something like this:

```
model switch
 input ComplicatedConnector icon[2];
 output ComplicatedConnector ocon;
 input Real x;
 equation
   if x >= 0 then
     connect(ocon, icon[1]);
   else
     connect(ocon, icon[2]);
   end if;
end switch;
```

This does not work. How can it be properly expressed in Modelica?

Answer based on comment by Adrian Pop.

```
model switch
 input ComplicatedConnector icon[2];
 output ComplicatedConnector ocon;
 input Real x;
 ComplicatedConnector con;
 initial equation
   con = icon[1];
 equation
   connect(ocon, con);
   when x >= 0 then
     con := icon[1];
   end when;
   when x < 0 then
     con := icon[2];
   end when;
end switch;
```

Update: The model above is wrong because ocon outputs the initial value of icon[1] forever if no event occurs which is not what you would expect from a switch. Note that this is not due to a wrong answer but due to my false interpretation of the answer. The following model is based on the answer by Michael Tiller.

```
model switch
 input ComplicatedConnector icon[2];
 output ComplicatedConnector ocon;
 input Real x;
 Integer k;
 initial equation
   k = 1;
 equation
   ocon = icon[k];
   when x >= 0 then
     k := 1;
   elsewhen x < 0 then
     k := 2;
   end when;
end switch;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is not possible. You can only switch them based on a parameter known at compile time (also known as structural parameter). The condition in the if equation containing connects needs to be a parameter expression.

Comment: The question is what do you want to model. It might work in some other way.

Comment: There is a way to disable connections together with a component using conditional components but the condition in the conditional component needs to be a parameter expression. See 4.4.5 Conditional Component Declaration in the Modelica Spec.

Comment: I want to route one of 2 (non-trivial) signals based on a dynamic condition. The trick used in Modelica.Blocks.Routing.Extractor does not work since * cannot be applied. How is this seemingly common problem modeled properly in Modelica?

Comment: I think the only way to do it is to connect them both and then depending on a when equation switch the values that go into each one.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `connect` statements are equations.  You can expand them out yourself.  They exist mainly to avoid "bookkeeping" errors for generating boilerplate equations.  So what I suggest you do is simply take your `switch` model and expand each `connect` into equations.  The it should work.